# How do I cancel a Task.Backgroundable using the IntelliJ Plugin SDK

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

If I create a background task like so... I can cancel it in the UI by clicking the "X"... however, I would also like the ability to cancel it programmatically.

```
public class MyTaskLauncher {
     public Map<String, Task.Backgroundable> myTasks = new HashMap<>();
     public myTaskLaunchMethod(){
         Task.Backgroundable myBgTask = new Task.Backgroundable(null, "MyTask", true, null) {

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    super.onCancel();
                    System.out.println("cancelling")
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinished() {
                    super.onFinished();
                }

                @Override
                public void run(@NotNull ProgressIndicator progressIndicator) {
                    
                    //do some work that I want to cancel programmatically somewhere else in my code
                }
            };

            Log.trace("Starting task...");
            ProgressManager.getInstance().run(myBgTask);
            myTasks.put("task1", myBgTask);
      }
 }
```

now the task runs, but if a particular event happens, I need to immediately stop that task.

```
     // somewhere else in my code, functionality I'm looking for.
     MyTaskLauncher.myTasks.get("task1").CancelTask()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback will be canceled when you throw a [`ProcessCanceledException`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/b9b4071d57b09efea0bd52ad8bced121ab123661/platform/util/base/src/com/intellij/openapi/progress/ProcessCanceledException.java#L23) from the `run()` method.
The code in `onCancel()` will then be executed.

From the definition and JavaDoc of the `onCancel()` method in the [`Task`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/b9b4071d57b09efea0bd52ad8bced121ab123661/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/progress/Task.java#L66-L71) interface:

```java
/**
 * This callback will be invoked on AWT dispatch thread.
 * <p>
 * Callback executed when run() throws {@link ProcessCanceledException} or if its {@link ProgressIndicator} was canceled.
 */
public void onCancel() { }
```